# Programmatically send SMS to customers when a order delivery status is changed

Tags: magento, sms

I want to send a notification SMS to customers when I change order delivery status from admin panel, purchased SMS service from India

Comment: Why don't you try this feature rich extension https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the order status for changing - there is no event for this so you need:

Event: `sales_order_load_after` to get the order status after load
Method:

```
public function fetchOrderStatus(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    try{
      if (!Mage::registry('cartware_order_status')){
        Mage::register('cartware_order_status', $observer->getOrder()->getStatus());
      }
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
      Mage::logException("UNEXPECTED PROBLEM WIH REGISTER");
      Mage::logException($e);
    }
    return;
  }
```

Event: `sales_order_save_after` to get the order status after save:
Method:

```
public function checkOrderStatus(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    try{
      if(!Mage::registry('cartware_order_status')){
        return;
      }else{
        $orderStatus = Mage::registry('cartware_order_status');
      }
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
      Mage::logException("UNEXPECTED PROBLEM WIH REGISTRY");
      Mage::logException($e);
    }

    if ($orderStatus != $observer->getOrder()->getStatus() &&
    $observer->getOrder()->getStatus() == [STATUS YOU WANT TO REACT IF CHANGE TO]){
       sendYourSmsMethod();
    }
  }
```

Good luck!

Comment: a shorter approach would maybe be to use the event: `sales_order_resource_save_attribute_after`

Comment: Hey Mischa, thanks for your quick answer. I am sorry I am bit new in Magento, was working in core php can you pl further guide me how to use these methods and events exactly and where?